# Using @input Observable in the view but the pipe function in the component is ignored

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my component i'm using an `@Input` that is type of `Observable`. In the view I'm using the `| async` pipe to handle the subscribe and unsubscribe of the Observable stream.
In the component I'm trying to `pipe` this Observable to perform some mutation on the stream. However the map function inside the pipe never gets triggered.

data.component.ts:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'data',
 template: `<div *ngFor="let item of (data$ | async)">{{item}}</div>`
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data$: Observable<IData>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$
      .pipe(
        map(next => {
          // do some data mutation
          // never getting in here
        })
      )
  }
}
```

Right now the map function inside the pipe never gets triggered and thus does not mutate the data as desired.
The desired outcome would be that the data mutation happens inside the map function.

Comment: You have to `subscribe`, otherwise the you won't receive any items.

Comment: The stream is already subscribe in the view. If I subscribe in there i'm mutating a different instance. This will have no effect on the view.

Comment: In your view you subscribe to `data$`? `pipe()` method doesn't modify the chain "in-place" so you have to assign it to a different variable and then use `| async` on that.

Comment: You mean something like this? `this.mutatedData$ = this.data$` and then `this.mutatedData$.pipe(map())`. In the view do `this.mutatedData$ | async`? Because that seems not to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `this.data$` inside the component.

```
this.data$.subscribe((data) => {
   //do data mutation
   // assign it to a local variable, say this.data
})
```

Along with it, if you want the mutation to be used in template, you can also assign the mutated data to a local variable and use that in the template.

Here's how it would look:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'data',
 template: `<div *ngFor="let item of mutatedData">{{item}}</div>`
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data$: Observable<IData>;
  mutatedData: IData;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$.subscribe((data) => {
       //do mutatation
       //assign mutated data to this.mutatedData
   });
  }
}
```

Update: As OP intends to avoid `subscribe` in the `component`, here's an idea:
Note: you can also write a custom pipe to do this, but for now, consider this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of mutatedData">{{mutate(item)}}</div>`
 })
 export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input()
   data$: Observable<IData>;

   mutate(data: any): any{
     //data mutation
     //return updated data
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Aragorn, thanks for the feedback. I would like to avoid subscribing inside the component.

Comment: @Nephi If you _have to_, then you can do that by calling a pure function from the template and mutating data in that function. Let me know if you want ideas on that...

Comment: I have tried to use pure functions in the template before and it can quickly greatly impact the performance of the application. Especially if your using it within a list like a *ngFor. At the moment I have used your solution provided above. If I don't receive any better answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to avoid subscribe in the component. But for your use case, that is a suitable approach.

Comment: When calling a function from the template angular wil reevaluate the result on every change detection. Best practice is to write a custom pipe to replace the `mutate()` function.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid subscribing and unsubscribing on hot observables the following approach can be used:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'data',
 template: `<div *ngFor="let item of (dataMutate$ | async)">{{item}}</div>`
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data$: Observable<IData>;

  dataMutate$: Observable<IData>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataMutate$ = this.data$
      .pipe(
        map(next => {
          // do some data mutation
          // never getting in here
        })
      )
  }
}
```

This avoids unsubscribing in the component and calling any [mutating function](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) that will be evaluated on every change detection.

Comment: but if  data$ will change after the onInit your way will not work no?